# Apply custom Bootstrap variables in Angular project

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to override the default colors of Bootstrap in my Angular project. I have created a `_variables.scss` file inside of my `src` folder.

Inside of this file I have added the following code: `$primary: purple;`

Then I have imported my `_variables.scss` file into my main `styles.scss` like this: `@import 'variables';`

I have also arranged my `angular.json` file so that my styles look like this:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

What I would like to achieve is that when i use the following code in my html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary auth-button">Sign in</button>
```

the color of my button should be purple.

I want to change more variables later on and on a few pages, thus this should be a global variable.

Comment: Want to check if you change the import order of styles?

Comment: In my `styles.scss` I only import my `_variables.scss`. My Bootstrap is included in app through `angular.json`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by removing Bootstrap from where I add it to my styles in `angular.json` and importing it manually in my `styles.scss`.

I have also changed my Bootstrap path in order to target the `scss` file. Here is my html code:

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

and here is my styles in `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use bootstrap-sass features, but using the minified css.

You will either need to:

1. use [bootstrap-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass)

   ```
   @import './_variables.scss';
   @import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap';
   ```
2. compile your own version of bootstrap with your theme and use that minified version.
3. If you are using [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/), you can use CSS variables instead

Answer (score 0):

you can change it with the class `btn-primary` of bootstrap in your `styles.scss` while importing your variables at the top using `import` of `_variables.scss`

```
.btn-primary {
   color: $primary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do it like that, but I basically want to override the color of `primary`. This way, anywhere I use `primary` this color will apply.